# Nested div applying margin outside box model

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble adding a margin to my `<figure>` while it is nested within the `<header>`.

When I apply `margin-top:10px` it is applying to the whole body instead of inside the `<header>` tag. I am also using `reset.css` if that helps at all.

This is for an assignment in college and can't get a hold of tutor for an answer.

**Code:**

```
<html>
   <body>
   <header>
      <figure></figure>
   </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body {
          backround-color: #f2f2f2;
          margin:0px;
          padding:0px;
    }
    header {
           display: block;
           position: static;
           max-width: 980px;
           height: 100px;
           background: #1e1e1e;
           margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    }
    header figure {
           margin-top:10px; /** when this margin top is added it creates a margin on the full page instead of inside the header**/
           margin-left:10px;
           max-width:200px;
           height:80px;
           background:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `padding` to the `header` instead. Use `box-sizing:border-box` as well which will prevent the padding from extending outward:

```
header {
   display: block;
   position: static;
   max-width: 980px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #1e1e1e;
   margin:0px auto;
   padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yhnfxs6x/)

Comment: I did try adding padding as well but it did extend the red box and I didn't know the box sizing: border-box; was a work around for that.  Thank you also for the great answer.

Comment: no problem, just an FYI about j08691's answer, if for some reason you have content that extends below the fixed header size...ex: maybe you have horizontal links and when the browser is made smaller they drop below the allowed header size...`overflow: auto` will cause scroll bars to show up in your header. Probably won't be a problem (especially in headers) but just something to be aware of it.

Comment: @JWoods correction, you can scroll now, the thing about `overflow` is it only contains the behavior, doesn't fix it. the "auto" behavior is when there is overflow the browser will add scrollbars so you can scroll to see more. You could use `overflow: hidden` which wont' add scrollbars but that can cause issues as well. If you have a dropdown menu inside your header that is set to `overflow: hidden` the menu will get cut off if it extends beyond the height of the header.

Comment: Yes I did in fact get scroll bars showing up which I couldn't have as its the main header for the project.  I applied your solution and still had a few problems with it but I think my main problem was the reset.css as I took it out and your solution then worked.  Thanks again

Comment: Yeah no problem. personally I don't find resets all that necessary. I apply `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to every element on the page and that is pretty much all you need as you can style the other elements yourself

Comment: @JWoods - Just to chime in here about the various methods, when using `overflow:auto` you'd only get scrollbars, as jmore mentions, if your header has a defined height. But a defined height wouldn't make much sense if you are worried about the viewport being reduced, in which case you should use media queries to create a responsive layout.

Comment: In my assignment from my lecturer I have to use the reset.css, and also I understand what you are saying @j08691 but how would I go around not defining a height to the header, would that not cause problems when viewing on a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is called [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). Add `overflow:auto` to your header to get the behavior you're after:

```
header {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    max-width: 980px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9swt7bp8/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, worked straight away.  Thank you .